# POSTing to a controller resource - should controllee's ID be part of controller URI, or a POST param?

Tags: rest

In my resource model I've got a "subscription" resource.  It goes through lifecycle states like "unsubscribed" -> "subscription pending" -> "subscribed" -> "unsubscription pending" -> "unsubscribed".

To allow clients to subscribe or unsubscribe a subscription, I'm planning to expose two controller resources (called "sub" and "unsub") for subscribing/unsubscribing the subscription, each accepting POST requests which will synchronously put the target subscription resource into the appropriate "pending" state, and asynchronously perform additional work to put the subscription into the "subscribed" or "unsubscribed" state.

I can think of a couple of ways for the client to designate the target subscription when making a POST request to "sub" or "unsub".  I could put the target subscription ID into the URI, like so:

/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/sub
or maybe
/sub/{subscription_id}

[Note: exposing the subscription ID in the URI would not present a security issue for my app.]

Or, I could make the subscription ID a POST param to:

/sub

Thoughts on which approach is preferable?  If you prefer the URI approach, which URI style do you like better, and why?

Note: a subscription which has been unsubscribed could subsequently be resubscribed, so the "unsubscribe" action is not equivalent to deletion of the subscription resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the ID a POST parameter to /subscription .

Instead of having a separate /unsubscribe resource, I would send a DELETE request to /subscription (passing in the ID in the same way).

I chose subscription instead of subscriber because there is ambiguity in subscriber as to whether you're creating/deleting subscriptions or actual subscribers/users.

EDIT - post-clarification.

REST uses the verbs GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. GET here doesn't make sense for creating/updating. You don't want DELETE because you want the resource to stay around. So I would recommend doing a POST for creating/starting a subscription and a PUT for modifying/unsubscribing a subscription. It's a slight misuse of the PUT verb but I think it fits your case a little better than the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Good point about ambiguity of the term "subscriber"; I'll rethink that name.  Regarding your main point: for my app, unsubscription is not deletion -- the subscription could theoretically be resubscribed in the future.  My fault for not mentioning that.  I initially thought to pass a form param like "action=subscribe" or "action=unsubscribe" to the subscription resource, but from what I've read, this amounts to tunneling, which is discouraged.  That's what led me in the direction of the two controller resources.

Comment: Note: I've updated the original question to rename the controller resource and clarify that unsubscribe != delete.

Comment: In response to your edits: in my app, a subscription is created via  POST to a subscriptions collection.  Using POST on the subscription resource for the subscribe operation and PUT for the unsubscribe operation seems insconsistent; the same verb for both seems preferable.  I'm using PUT to change the state of the subscription (excluding lifecycle state), e.g. to change the name.  However, I view subscribing/unsubscribing as operations rather than just state changes (although state is affected), so I'm leaning toward POST, but trying to avoid tunneling, hence the controller resources.

Comment: Upon rereading your comment, I may have misinterpreted it the first time.  I think you're saying use POST for creation (I agree) and PUT for both the subscribe and unsubscribe actions.  I'm wavering, but I see your point.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer.  There is more than one way to do it, and I've described another approach in my answer, but you were the only one to respond, and your feedback helped lead me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'm going to give another answer based on further research and consideration.

Ultimately, if you're following the HATEOAS principle, URIs other than top-level ones are effectively opaque to clients, and thus from the client's perspective, it doesn't really matter all that much whether the controllee is identified in the URI of the controller or not.  As a practical and aesthetic matter from the service's perspective, leaving it out of the controller's URI keeps it shorter and simpler, so there's that.

On the other hand, exposing the controllee in the URI would allow intermediaries (e.g. a router or firewall) to more easily examine and act on that exposed value, which could be useful in some situations.

For my project, I ultimately decided to expose one controller resource at the URI /subscription_tasks, accepting POSTs which include an action (subscribe/unsubscribe) and the target subscription ID as form parameters in the POST payload.  The POST returns a subscription_task resource which can be monitored via GET polling until the task is complete.